# Find Text between Html Tags

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on HtmlDocument and want to get text between tags:

```
<span>Location:</span><br/>                                 
50 Airport Road<br/>
Ottawa, CA <br/><br/>
<span>Latitude / Longitude:</span><br/>
40.32083 / -71.67275<br/><br/>
```

I want two things:

- 50 Airport Road 
  Ottawa, CA
- 45.32083 / -75.672775

How to do this.
Thanks in  Advance.
My english is not good please ignore.

Comment: Have you even tried asking Prof. Dr. Google for help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the HTML Agility Pack, which includes a DOM parser - it is never worth writing your own parser or RegExs for HTML.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

In the example below, you can see how easy it is to select an element using XPATH. Because the values you want aren't actually in an element, I'm using `text()` to get them.

If this were part of a larger document, you would expand the XPATH to reflect their location in the wider document.

```
string html = @"<span>Location:</span><br/>                                 
    50 Airport Road<br/>
    Ottawa, CA <br/><br/>
    <span>Latitude / Longitude:</span><br/>
    40.32083 / -71.67275<br/><br/>";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

// Getting an element (Location:)
var latLongLabel = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("span[2]");

// The location is split over two text nodes
var locationValA = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("text()[1]").InnerHtml.Trim();
var locationValB = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("text()[2]").InnerHtml.Trim();

// The lat long
var latLongVal = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("text()[4]").InnerHtml.Trim();
```

Comment: I think its good as comment, but answer should contain also example.

Comment: I have added a specific example.